# What distance has the soldier travelled?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, speed

> A troop $5$ meters long starts marching. A soldier at the end of the file steps out and starts marching forward at a higher speed. On reaching the head of the column, he immediately turns around and marches back at the same speed. As soon as he reaches the end of the file, the troop stops marching, and it is found that the troop has moved by exactly $5$ meters. What distance has the soldier travelled?

I thought that some info is lacking until my friend showed it in a book. How to get the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The key is to decompose the going ahead and going back intervals. Let $x$ be the distance the troop has marched by the time the soldier gets to the head. How far has he traveled? How far will he travel back?

Use the fact that each interval lasts the same time for both the soldier and the troop. If their corresponding speeds are $v_s$ and $v_t$, then how can you get the times as a function of $x$, $v_s$ and $v_t$?

You will find out that you can get a relation $v_s = \alpha v_t$ and the value of $x$ by reducing those equations. What is the total distance then?